# How to make join query in jsp restful webservice?

Tags: sql, jsp, rest, join, web

I have one table of customer and second of feedback..Comman field between them is CustomerId. I know sql join query but I want a query for restful webservice in JSP. I am writing this below code which is throwing Internal server error(500).
I hink it will need a custom class because in result we are returning a List<>. but I dont know exactly.

```html
@GET
        @Path("/all")
        @Produces({"application/json"})
        public List<Feedback> find() {
            return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT f.feedback,c.firstName FROM Feedback f INNERJOIN Customerdetail c on f.customerId=c.customerId")
                    .getResultList();
        }



    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
    Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT f.feedback,c.firstName FROM Feedback f INNERJOIN Customerdetail c on f.customerId=c.customerId]. 
    [46, 47] The FROM clause has 'Feedback f' and 'INNERJOIN Customerdetail' that are not separated by a comma.
    [71, 72] The FROM clause has 'INNERJOIN Customerdetail' and 'c on' that are not separated by a comma.
    [76, 77] The FROM clause has 'c on' and 'f.customerId=' that are not separated by a comma.
    [89, 90] The FROM clause has 'f.customerId=' and 'c.customerId' that are not separated by a comma.
    [74, 76] The identification variable 'on' cannot be a reserved word.
    [89, 90] The identification variable '=' cannot be a reserved word.
    [102, 102] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.

    root cause

    Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
    Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT f.feedback,c.firstName FROM Feedback f INNERJOIN Customerdetail c on f.customerId=c.customerId]. 
    [46, 47] The FROM clause has 'Feedback f' and 'INNERJOIN Customerdetail' that are not separated by a comma.
    [71, 72] The FROM clause has 'INNERJOIN Customerdetail' and 'c on' that are not separated by a comma.
    [76, 77] The FROM clause has 'c on' and 'f.customerId=' that are not separated by a comma.
    [89, 90] The FROM clause has 'f.customerId=' and 'c.customerId' that are not separated by a comma.
    [74, 76] The identification variable 'on' cannot be a reserved word.
    [89, 90] The identification variable '=' cannot be a reserved word.
    [102, 102] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look up here how to query with JPQL or using Native queries. It will also be helpful if you show us your schema and describe what exactly you want to select.
JPQL or Native Querying:
 [JPQL Querying](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this link
 https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#Join_Fetch_and_Query_Optimization

. Here you will have all queries related to JSP API. Also Use custom class to have better result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake in your query: `INNER JOIN` NOT `INNERJOIN`.